# How to iterate an array and compare each element with other elements in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array. I try to analyze each element (each element is a character) and compare if each element individually is equal to another character, something like this:

(The following code is incorrect, only illustrative)

```
let array = ["5","a","5","8","l","j"]
var finalString = ""
for i in array {
    if array[i] = ["^0-9"] {
        //Compares if the element in position i is equal to a number between 0 - 9
        finalString + "1 " //or do something else
    } else if array[i] = ["^a-z"] {
        //Compares if the element in position i is equal to a character between a - z
        finalString + "2 " //or do something else
    }
}
print(finalString)
//Expected output
// 1 2 1 1 2 2
```

I hope the explanation of my problem is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to find out more about the possible input values.

```
let array = ["5","a","5","8","l","j"]

let finalString = array.reduce("") { result, character in
    switch character {
    case "0"..."9": return result.appending("1 ")
    case "a"..."z": return result.appending("2 ")
    default: assertionFailure("\(character) is unexpected input"); return result
    }
}

print(finalString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues. The following code cleans up those issues and makes use of `CharacterSet` to see if the array elements contains numbers or letters.

```
let array = ["5","a","5","8","l","j"]
var finalString = ""
for str in array {
    if str.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil {
        //Compares if the string contains any digits
        finalString += "1 " //or do something else
    } else if str.rangeOfCharacter(from: .letters) != nil {
        //Compares if the string contains any letters
        finalString += "2 " //or do something else
    } else {
        finalString += "0 " //or do something else
    }
}
print("Res: \(finalString)")
```

Output:

> Res: 1 2 1 1 2 2

These particular checks are slightly different from the checks you mention in your code but for your example it gives the same result.

If you only want to accept 0-9 or a-z then you would need to update the specific character set being used.

Comment: Ok, I see, but if for example, if my array were not characters, and instead of characters had strings, what could I do in that case?

Comment: Actually, my code works if the array contains strings.

Comment: @rmaddy for strings you would need to invert the set and check if equals nil and not empty to make sure it has only letters

Comment: @LeoDabus No, my code works as-is. I ran my code in the playground and I get the desired output.

Comment: @ColeMacGrath I don't understand what you are asking. If you have a whole new requirement you should post a new question after closing this one.